# Link errors when linking LLVM

Tags: c++, llvm

So I'm following the LLVM Kaleidoscope tutorial (I have LLVM 3.4 on a Ubuntu 14.04 box) and I get a LOT of link errors like:

```
/test.cpp:542: undefined reference to `llvm::getGlobalContext()'
test.cpp:556: undefined reference to `llvm::Module::Module(llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&)'
```

Even If I explicitly copy and paste the code listing from the website into a seperate file, I still get the errors.

I compile by doing

```
clang++ -g -O3 test.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core`
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've done this:

```
dzur:~> cp ~/sources/llvm/examples/Kaleidoscope/Chapter3/toy.cpp .
dzur:~> clang++ -g toy.cpp `~/builds/build-llvm/Debug+Asserts/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core`
```

and it's working fine on my (also ubuntu) system. The llvm-config referenced there is my build of top of tree llvm. I haven't tried with one of the previous releases as I don't have them handy, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out that if I remove the --system-libs flag it will compile without issue. I know this will probably bring out other bugs but it solves this problem.